# In Python 3 how can I patch a function inside a module for unit testing?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have decorated methods that send timings to a hosted graphite instance they look like what is below

**views.py**

```
from util import send_timing

@send_timing('login')
def login_user():

    if is_user_ok():
        return True
    return False

@send_timing('get_user_info')
def get_user_info():

    return get_that_info()
```

I have a util file that defines the decorator

**util.py**

```
def send_timing(f):
  def decorated(*args):
     make_network_connection()
     ret = f(*args)
  return decorated
```

I have some unit tests

**test.py**

```
from views import *
import unittest

class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):

   def test_login(self):         
      self.assertTrue(login_user())
```

Now the problem is that call to `login_user`. It invokes the send_timing decorator which in turn makes a network connection. This makes my tests volatile and non-deterministic. Is there an easy way (python 3.3) to patch `send_timing` with a dummy or mock globally for all my tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [`@functools.wraps()` decorator factory](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) in your decorator:

```
from functools import wraps

def send_timing(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        # probably do a little more than just proxy
        return f(*args, **kw)
    return wrapper
```

This adds an attribute *on the returned wrapper function*, letting you access the original unwrapped function:

```
unwrapped = login_user.__wrapped__
```

You can use the `unwrapped` value here to mock `login_user`, or use it directly in your unit tests.